# How to set properly a SPF record in WHM

Tags: whm, spf

we ran a test in https://www.mail-tester.com/ by sending an email for mail spam test and this was the result:

[image: Test Result]

then we tried to add that SPF record in our WHM page like this:

1. [image]

2.
[image]

its been more than 12 hours since we applied that change but the problem still remains, how do we fix that?

Comment: I have not been able to find your DNS TXT record doing a lookup. Have you removed the records again? If not it could be that there is a problem with the DNS server setup. And as mentioned by @Bubba your record will only allow one specific IP address to send mail for the domain, and this can give problems if using your web-providers servers, since they may use multiple servers for sending mail.

Answer (score 0):

There could be more email servers responsible for sending your email. Therefore, you must enter SPF record provided by your web host and not the one recommended by mail-tester.com

with **-all** in SPF record, you're hard failing all other email servers and just allowing one.

It's also possible that there is no email server on your given IP address because some web hosts use third party email servers to send you email. In this case, they will provide you SPF record for the party email servers.

Putting right SPF record, as provided by your web host / email host would solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the SPF DNS you added is right for now, it's the most efficient form. But to @bubba's note, if you start mailing through a campaign manager, you'll have to update it.

If you follow the link below and change the dropdown to Authorative SOA Server

```
https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/dnstools/spf/soyplus.net/
```

SOA stands for "Statement of Authority" all other DNS Providers will pull from this server. You can see that your SOA is not publishing your SPF Record. 
[image]

That tells me that for some reason your hosting company is not applying the change, even-though it shows up in  WHM. You're DMARC record is not showing up either. You should call your host and ask them and when you get everything straightened out use this [email tester](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/mail-tester/).

Another thing you can try is to remove the `"` around the entry and see if that works, it really depends on the interface if you need to add the quotes or not.

Answer (score 0):

Best method to do authentication (DKIM + SPF) by cPanel

1. Open cPanel
2. Find Authentication
3. Disable DKIM and SPF
4. Re-enable DKIM and SPF

It will do all and auto config and you will see 100% correct information on https://www.mail-tester.com/